# Mean and variance of a joint distribution $f(x,y)$, if only given its copula

Tags: joint-distribution, independence, moments, copula

If the marginal data $X$ and $Y$ of a bivariate joint distribution $f(x,y)$ are unknown, but the copula function (or copula density) of the joint distribution is given, can the moments, mean and variance of the joint distribution be backed out from the copula alone?

If not, what traditional statistical measures about $f(x,y)$ *can* be extracted from the copula and how?

Comment: Consider (X*,Y*) = (2X,3Y+4). Is the copula changed as you go from (X,Y) to (X*,Y*)? Are their means and variances the same?

Comment: you're saying that linear transformations of the marginals, and therefore changes to their moments, will not alter the copula?

Comment: Yes, even any *monotonic* transformation will not alter copulas. I restricted my Socratic question to linear transformations because it's easier to compute the effect on means and variances in that case. If you're going to separate marginal distribution from dependence structure you need invariance to monotonic transformation. The answer to the part you added at the end is 'whatever is unchanged by monotonic transformation'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the whole point of the copula is to separate the marginal distributions and their dependence structure. For a given copula, any distributions can be the marginal distributions, so you’ll not get anything about the marginals from the copula.

Comment: the question was about getting the moments of the joint distribution, $\mu_{1,2}, \sigma_{1,2}$, not of the marginals, $\mu_1, \sigma_1, \mu_2, \sigma_2$. besides this, you are saying then that a joint distribution's moments can't be solved unless the marginals' moments are given, in other words, the former requires the latter, even though the joint distribution can be viewed as its own entity whose moments are not a function of some dependence structure, in spite of its hidden underlying components

Comment: @develarist: What is $\mu_{1,2}$ if not $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$? Besides, write out the moment integral using the copula and see what you need and are missing.

Comment: am i mixing up joint distributions with mixture distributions?

Comment: How could we guess?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mu_{1,2}$?